# How to round the floating point precision, regard to the size of it?

Tags: java, double, rounding

It's easy to round the value to a specific number of decimal positions:

```
public static double round(double x, int n){
    n = (int)Math.pow(n, 10);
    return Math.round(x*n)/n;
}
```

But can you make an algorithm that can presuppose how many decimal places it would actually need to round up depending on how large the number is? 

I mean, if the number is huge (like `100000000.12345`) it wouldn't need that much of decimal precision so it can round it up to lets say 1 or 2 decimal places, 

While if a number is pretty slight (say like `0.00012345`) it would need maximum decimal precision
What's the idea to do something like this?

**EDIT:**
Example:

```
 argument       returned   decnum           comment
123456789.9    123456789     0    //number is way too large so I don't need any decimal places
12345678.99    12345678      0    //number is still very large.
1234567.899    1234567       0    //still...
123456.7899    123456        0    //...
12345.67899    12345         0    //...
1234.567899    1234          0    //It's pretty large now. Still not small enough to get some decimals.
123.4567899    123.4         1    //Now, number is a little average, so 1 decimal place is included.
12.34567899    12.34         2    //The number is normal, so I want a normal 2 decimal places 
1.234567899    1.234         3    //Now it's kinda small, so it now gives 3 decimal places
.1234567899    0.1234        4    //Smaller number, thus greater number of decimal places (4).
.0123456789    0.01234       5    //Even smaller
.0012345678    0.0012345     7    //Larger number of decimal places.
.0001234567    0.0001234567  10   //Smaller and smaller number, greater and greater number of decimals.
```

I'm just looking for a way
where I can **INCREASE** number of decimals when the number is getting closer to zero,
And **DECREASE** the decimal-number as the number gets away from zero.

Comment: The definition of rounding means you lose precision, the number of decimal places you round to is an arbitrary decision you make as the author of the software.

Comment: @jbabey That's my question! I need that to be dynamic!

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc
No.

Comment: No, it isn't 'easy to round the value to a specific number of decimal positions' at all, unless the value is already in base-10. As doubles are in base-2, they can't be rounded to a specific number of decimal positions at all. They don't *have* decimal positions. If you want decimal positions you must use base-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From algorithm point of view, I would follow the steps below:

1. Convert the number in base 10 format e.g. 123456789.9 -> 1.234567899 * 10^8 and 0.0001234567 --> 1.234567 * 10^-4.
2. Look at the power factors of 10 e.g. `8` in the first example and `-4` in the last example.
3. Compute the precision place requirement by adjusting a factor. Just an example could be as `(-1*(p-3))`, where `p` is the power factor. If the number comes negative then use '0'.

This will result into following numbers.

> ```
> argument       decnum      
> 123456789.9    -1*(8-3) = -5 -> 0
> 12345678.99    -1*(7-3) = -4 -> 0
> 1234567.899    -1*(6-3) = -3 -> 0
> 123456.7899    -1*(5-3) = -2 -> 0
> 12345.67899    -1*(4-3) = -1 -> 0
> 1234.567899    -1*(3-3) =  0 -> 0
> 123.4567899    -1*(2-3) = 1  -> 1
> 12.34567899    -1*(1-3) = 2  -> 2
> 1.234567899    -1*(0-3) = 3  -> 3
> .1234567899    -1*(-1-3) = 4 -> 4
> .0123456789    -1*(-2-3) = 5  -> 5
> .0012345678    -1*(-3-3) = 6  -> 6
> .0001234567    -1*(-4-3) = 7  -> 7
> ```

This would be very close to what you are looking for. Try adjusting the factor and the formula to get more closer, if you really want to (this is just an algorithm/aproach).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `BigDecimal`. Create a `BigDecimal` with your `double` value then check the scale with `bigDVariable.scale()` and round with the wanted scale depending on the value returned by it and its value. [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) doc.

Edit : You don't seem to worry about how many decimals you have in the first place, the value of your `double` looks to be the only information that matters. Checking `scale()` wouldn't matter then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want high precision (significant digits), you'll have to use `BigDecimal` instead of double.  The `BigDecimal` round method gives you the number of significant digits you ask for.

Here's something I put together.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Rounding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(100000000.12345);
        System.out.println("Number: " + number.toPlainString());
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int precision = 8; precision < 17; precision++) {
            System.out.println("Precision: " + precision + ", result: "
                    + round(number, precision));
        }
    }

    public static String round(BigDecimal number, int precision) {
        MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(precision, 
                RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal rounded = number.round(mathContext);
        return rounded.toPlainString();
    }

}
```

And here are the results.

```
Number: 100000000.12344999611377716064453125

Precision: 8, result: 100000000
Precision: 9, result: 100000000
Precision: 10, result: 100000000.1
Precision: 11, result: 100000000.12
Precision: 12, result: 100000000.123
Precision: 13, result: 100000000.1234
Precision: 14, result: 100000000.12345
Precision: 15, result: 100000000.123450
Precision: 16, result: 100000000.1234500
```

.

```
Number: 0.00012344999999999999203137424075293893110938370227813720703125

Precision: 8, result: 0.00012345000
Precision: 9, result: 0.000123450000
Precision: 10, result: 0.0001234500000
Precision: 11, result: 0.00012345000000
Precision: 12, result: 0.000123450000000
Precision: 13, result: 0.0001234500000000
Precision: 14, result: 0.00012345000000000
Precision: 15, result: 0.000123450000000000
Precision: 16, result: 0.0001234500000000000
```